# How to set connection pool size for Apache Derby's ClientConnetionPoolDataSource

Tags: java, spring, derby

I am using org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientConnectionPoolDataSource as my data source to connect to my derby networkServer databse but I am not able to figure out how to set a pool size for this connection pool. IS there a way to set a pool size at all? If so, how can I configure it using spring xml configuration?

Comment: Possibly your problems are related to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-4719 and http://markmail.org/message/4t2p4pmmoj5z5xlo#query:+page:1+mid:nmd5jhd3wks4s7jw+state:results, though it's hard to fully tell from your description.

Comment: I am not technically facing a problem. Everything works fine but I just want to be able to specify a size for the pool that is used by the ClientConnectionPoolDataSource like we can do for Oracle thin driver.